# How trigger click event after v-model's change on vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a checkBox on vuejs. I  call a function when it's status changes, but click  event triggers before the v-model changes. So the value of v-model in  the function is the previous value. How Can I  make the click event trigger after the v-model's change?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      status: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkBoxClicked() {
      console.log(this.status)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox"
      @click.native="checkBoxClicked"
    >
      I accept the terms and use
   </b-form-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: move the logic of your click event to a watcher instead of handling the click event.

Comment: It is not such that easy in my project, needs so many changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `change` event instead of `click`:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox"
      @change="checkBoxClicked"
    >
      I accept the terms and use
   </b-form-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@atousadarabi
How about if you wait until the next render cycle, does that help?

```
methods: {
   checkBoxClicked() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
         console.log(this.status)
      })
   }
}
```

Otherwise just remove the click handler all together and have a watcher on `status`. Whenever it updates do what you need to :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me.